# Updating SlickGrid Options after initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

My question regarding SlickGrid is this.

If I create a grid with options { enableCellNavigation: true }, can I later, edit the grid options to set this value to false?

I can access the options via the getOptions(); function but assigning a new value does nothing.
Have also tried calling the render() and init() methods again afterwards but no change.

Wondering if this is possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has always worked for me:

```
grid.setOptions({
  editable: false,
  autoEdit: false
});
grid.invalidate();
```